# Better solution for inserting objects for update loop

Tags: java, arrays, game-engine

So I'm new to game development and dont know any patterns yet. Trying to figure it all out by myself and here is a problem that I stuck with.

I have this level called BowLevel. It has update method which updates List of enemies, handles collision and so on.

However the way I implemented adding objects to these Lists feels wrong. It just doesnt  really makes sense.

Here is my constructor for abstract `Enemy` class

```
public Enemy (Vector2 position, int level)
{
    this.position = position;
    BowLevel.enemies.add(this);
    state = PawnState.WALK;
    this.level = level;
}
```

With that I wont be able to add an Enemy to any other levels other than this.
But passing my level object into every single constructor for all classes seems wrong too.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: `"With that I wont be able to add an Enemy to any other levels other than this."` -- this doesn't make sense. How will this restrict adding another Enemy object to a different level?

Comment: 1) don't make it static, and 2) you're just adding one instance to the enemies collection, you can add others that go to other levels. 3) It's probably best if you have the Game handle its own enemies collection including what gets added and how, rather than have it change state based on a side effect from the Enemy constructor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels would be something like `enemies.add (new Enemy())` be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code, you have a bunch of levels, each one being a class, and you are storing enemies in each level as a static `ArrayList`, therefore you don't know how to add to different levels.

The correct OO approach would be to define a class `Level` which defines methods common to all the levels (not as static). For example, you could have:

```
class Level {
  private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addEnemy(Enemy en) {
  }
  ...
}
```

now your `BowLevel` class could look like this:

```
class BowLevel extends Level {
  public BowLevel() {
    // do something here which is level specific... 
    //perhaps create the enemies?
    addEnemy(new Enemy(....));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh. That's probably what I was looking for. But it seems to me that it'll be easier if I have static list of enemies, since I cant load and play 2 levels at the same time. And with static addEnemy method.

Comment: @maklas: please do yourself a favor and get these statics out of your mind. You're risking shooting yourself in the foot with use of them.